# using pxloader with require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

**Hello everyone,**

I'm currently implementing the [pxloader](http://thinkpixellab.com/pxloader/) js library to get all my site's images preloaded. 
But it's somehow not willing to work alongside the require.js .. I'm not sure though whether I'm initializing the library correctly or if the library is in correct format to be loaded through the require.js.

Please see the below example:

**index.jsp**

```
<script src="jscripts/lib/require.js" data-main="jscripts/common"></script>
<script> require(['./app/Preloader/controler']); </script>
```

**common.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'jscripts',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery/jquery',
        domReady: 'lib/domReady',
        PxLoader: 'lib/pxloader/PxLoader',
        PxLoaderImage: 'lib/pxloader/PxLoaderImage',
        Preloader: 'lib/preloader/img_preloader',   
    }
    });

requirejs(['jquery', 'domReady', 'Cookies'], function ($, domReady,  cookies, img_preloader) 
{});
```

**constroler.js**

```
require(['common'], function()
{
    require(['Preloader', 'domReady', 'PxLoader'], function(Preloader,domReady,pxloader ){

        var preloader = new Preloader();
        domReady(function ()
        {
            preloader.LoadImagesDB(function(){ console.log('OK');});
        });
    });
});
```

**img_preloader.js**

```
define(function (require) {
    function Preloader() {
    }

    Preloader.prototype = (function ()
    {
        var PxLoaderImage = require('PxLoaderImage');
        var PxLoader = require('PxLoader');

        var LoadImagesDB = function (ok_callback)
        {
            ...
            PxLoader.add(PxLoaderImage("image1.png"));
            PxLoader.add(PxLoaderImage("image2.png"));
            ...

            PxLoader.addProgressListener(function(e) { 
                percent = Math.round( e.completedCount / e.totalCount * 100 );
                $("#progress").html(percent);
            }); 

            PxLoader.addCompletionListener(function(e) { 
                ok_callback();
            }); 

            PxLoader.start();
        },

        return{
            LoadImagesDB : LoadImagesDB
        };
    })();
return Preloader;
});
```

Now the Pxloader throws an error every time I call pxloader.add(..) method.

```
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
  img_preloader.js:31 LoadImagesDB 
  img_preloader.js:31(anonymous function) 
  controler.js:8 runCallbacks 
  domReady.js:20 callReady 
  domReady.js:31 pageLoaded"
```

[Here](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/PxLoader) you can find the source of above mentioned Pxloader library.

Can anyone please advise me whether it's something in my code that is wrong or it's just he library not being formatted correctly...

(apologies for my bad english)

Any help would be greatily appreciated,
Alex

Comment: You say the `TypeError` is generated when you call `PxLoader.add(...)`. Fair enough? But what specific line of code generates it? With the information you give here, it could be that it is generated **inside** `PxLoader.add`. Please add a precise stack trace to your question.

Comment: I have updated the main post with the full stack trace. btw. There is the first PxLoader.add() call on line 31.

Comment: I have tested the library without require.js and it's working without any issues. I suspect that require.js is not loading the library properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have fixed the issue ... I just needed to instantiate the Pxloader() object.

**img_preloader.js**

```
define(['PxLoader', 'PxLoaderImage', 'Cookies'], function( PxLoader, PxLoaderImage, cookies) 
    function Preloader() {
    }

    Preloader.prototype = (function ()
    {
        var loader = new PxLoader(); 

        var LoadImagesDB = function (ok_callback)
        {
            ...
            loader.add(PxLoaderImage("image1.png"));
            loader.add(PxLoaderImage("image2.png"));
            ...

            loader.addProgressListener(function(e) { 
                percent = Math.round( e.completedCount / e.totalCount * 100 );
                $("#progress").html(percent);
            }); 

            loader.addCompletionListener(function(e) { 
                ok_callback();
            }); 

            loader.start();
        },

        return{
            LoadImagesDB : LoadImagesDB
        };
    })();
return Preloader;
});
```